# Cross-compiling package that uses a cross-compiled library

Tags: openwrt

I'm trying to write an OpenWRT package that uses a dynamically linked library that I cross-compile too. As far as I can tell compiling the library into a `.so` file works fine. After compiling `find . -name "libname.so"` inside the root directory returns the following:

```
./staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/root-ar71xx/usr/lib/libname.so
./staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libname.so
./build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/libname-1.0/ipkg-ar71xx/libname/usr/lib/libname.so
./build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/libname-1.0/libname.so
./build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/root-ar71xx/usr/lib/libname.so
```

How exactly do I use this to link the library to my project? In my projects Makefile I have:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=blocker
PKG_VERSION:=1
PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/blocker
    TITLE:=$(PKG_NAME)
    SECTION:=util
    CATEGORY:=Utilities
    DEPENDS:=+libname
endef

TARGET_CFLAGS += -Wall -llibname

define Package/blocker/description
    Blocks incomming SSH and HTTP connections
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) $(PKG_JOBS) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) \
    $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)
endef

define Package/blocker/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/sbin/
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/etc/config
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/etc/init.d
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/files/blocker.init $(1)/etc/init.d/blocker
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/files/blocker.conf $(1)/etc/config/blocker
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/blocker $(1)/sbin/blocker
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,blocker))
```

However, compiling this package throws an error:

```
#include <libname.h> // <-- fatal error: libname.h: No such file or directory

int main(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Header files are not the same thing as libraries - I'm not familiar with that Makefile syntax, but you will probably need to modify the `TARGET_CFLAGS` to add an include file search path of the form `-I path/to/dir` where `dir` is the containing directory for `libname.h`. (As an aside, `TARGET_CFLAGS` may not be the appropriate place for `-llibname` either - I would have expected that to belong in a `LDFLAGS` type variable.)

Answer (score -1):

After compiling libname librarry in installation block install the libname.h file in ?(1)/usr/lib, so that when you compile your package it can locate the header.